# How to turn change numbers in 2darrays of random number using recusion in java?

Tags: java

With a set of 8*8 2d array that is already assigned with random 1 and 2 ,after finding the first 1 in the first row,and change it to 0, how could a recursion of method use to change all the 1 surround to 0(from all direction） and stop when it touch 2.

for example
1 2 2 1 2 2 1 1
1 1 2 2 1 2 1 1
2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1
2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1
2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2
2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2
2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2
1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1

to
0 2 2 1 2 2 1 1
0 0 2 2 1 2 1 1
2 0 2 1 1 2 1 1
2 0 2 1 2 1 1 1
2 0 2 2 2 2 1 2
2 0 2 2 0 2 2 2
2 2 0 0 0 2 0 2
0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0

Comment: And you have tried what?

Comment: This looks like homework. If you want help then make sure you show that you have at least attempted to solve it on your own (i.e. post your code) and show exactly what part of the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: you should post your code whatever you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to minesweeper.

You would start with which ever index you please and then there are 8 points you could possibly check.

1. Top left
2. Top
3. Top Right
4. Right
5. Bottom Right
6. Bottom
7. Bottom Left
8. Left

You would then call your recursive function, making sure that each new index that you are checking is a valid index of the array (Numbers in between and including 0 and length - 1).

For example:

```
public void reveal(int index1, int index2) {

    // Quit if number is a 2
    if(array[index1][index2] == 2)
        return;
    else {
         // Check for correct index before calling
         ...
         // Then
         reveal(index1-1,index2-1);
         reveal(index1-1,index2);
         reveal(index1-1,index2+1);
         reveal(index1,index2+1);
         reveal(index1+1,index2+1);
         reveal(index1+1,index2);
         reveal(index1+1,index2-1);
         reveal(index1,index2-1);
    }
}
```